# como cambiar el estado de un boolean en mysql jsf

Tags: java, jsf, spring, primefaces

como puedo cambiar el estado del vendedor, lo que quiero es modificar el estado con solo hacer click en el link, y que se cambie en la base de datos
[image: booleanvendedor]
este es mi managedbean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class VendedorManagedBean {

private Vendedor vendedor  =new Vendedor();

private List<Vendedor> vendedores = new ArrayList<Vendedor>();

private List<Local> locales = new ArrayList<Local>();

@ManagedProperty(value="#{vendedorService}")
private VendedorService vendedorService;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{localService}")
private LocalService localService;



public String editar(){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, String> params = context.getExternalContext()
                                    .getRequestParameterMap();

    String id = params.get("vendedorId");

    vendedor = vendedorService.getVendedorRepositoryy()
                        .findOne(new Long(id));

    return "editar_vendedor";
}
public String buscar2(boolean estado){
    vendedores = vendedorService.getVendedorRepositoryy().obtenerVendedorporestado(estado); 
    return null;
}
public String buscar(){
    vendedores = vendedorService.getVendedorRepositoryy().obtenerVendedorporestado(vendedor.isEstado());    
    return null;
}
public String eliminar(){
    Long id = vendedor.getId();
    vendedorService.getVendedorRepositoryy().delete(id);
    vendedor = new Vendedor();
    return "registro_vendedor"; 
}

public String guardar(){
    vendedorService.getVendedorRepositoryy().save(vendedor);
    vendedor = new Vendedor();
    return "registro_vendedor";
}

public Vendedor getVendedor() {
    return vendedor;
}

public void setVendedor(Vendedor vendedor) {
    this.vendedor = vendedor;
}

public List<Vendedor> getVendedores() {
    vendedores = Lists.newArrayList(vendedorService.getVendedorRepositoryy().findAll());
    return vendedores;
}

public void setVendedores(List<Vendedor> vendedores) {
    this.vendedores = vendedores;
}

public List<Local> getLocales() {
    locales = Lists.newArrayList(localService.getLocalRepositoryy().findAll());

    return locales;
}

public void setLocales(List<Local> locales) {
    this.locales = locales;
}

public VendedorService getVendedorService() {
    return vendedorService;
}

public void setVendedorService(VendedorService vendedorService) {
    this.vendedorService = vendedorService;
}

public LocalService getLocalService() {
    return localService;
}

public void setLocalService(LocalService localService) {
    this.localService = localService;
}
}
```

ademas, el estado debe estar por defecto en activo, como podria insertarlo sin incluirlo visualmente en el formulario

Answer (score 1):

Sería bueno ver el código que tiene en `facelets`, pero ésta implementación es bien directa:

1. Crear un [dataTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/dataTable.html) que renderiza la lista proveniente de la DB
2. a cada "hipervínculo" le creas un componente de tipo: [commandLink](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/commandLink.html)
3. Al componente `commandLink` se le asigna un `action=""` que llama un método en un backing bean (ManagedBean), e.g: `action="#{vendedorManagedBean.toggleState()}"`
4. El método `toggleState()..` lo que hace es llamar a un servicio que va a cambiar el estado del "vendedor".

**No lo he probado pero espero que funcione:**

**Facelet: admin-vendedor.xhtml**

```
<h:dataTable value="#{vendedorManagedBean.vendedores}" var="vendedor">

  // el resto de las columnas ....

  <h:column>
   <f:facet name="header">estado</f:facet>
   <h:commandLink value="#{vendedorManagedBean.estadoVendedorStr(vendedor.id)}"
                  action="#{vendedorManagedBean.toggleState(vendedor)}" />
  </h:column>


</h:dataTable>
```

**ManagedBean:**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class VendedorManagedBean {

// el resto de las propiedades y métodos ... 

private String estadoVendedorStr;

public String estadoVendedorStr([tipo_dato_id_vendedor] id){
  Vendedor v = vendedores.get(id);
  if(v.getEstado().equals(ACTIVO)){
    return "Activo";
  }
  return "Inactivo";
}

public String toggleState(Vendedor v){
   servicioDB.cambiarEstado(v);
   return "admin-vendedor?faces-redirect=true";
}

}
```

**Consejo**
No es muy recomendado que deje *VendedorMAnagedBean* de tipo `@SessionScope`, si quiere pasar información de una página a otra, hay otras formas de lograr ésto sin que se necesite utilizar éste *scope*, por ejemplo  puede utilizar [viewParam](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/toc.htm)

algo asi:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="vendedorId" value="#{vendedorManagedBean.vendedorPedidoId}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{vendedorManagedBean.buscarVendedorPedido()}" />
</f:metadata>
```

Y en el managed bean lo que se hace es crear lo siguiente para establecer la info:

```
// setter y getter para  vendedorPedidoId

public void buscarVendedorPedido(){
   vendedor = servicioDB.buscarVendedorPorID(vendedorPedidoId);
}
```

Comment: gracias, la probare a ver si funciona